# xubuntu core doesnt let me zip large files

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, archive

im running xubuntu-core (xfce 4.14) on a remote VPS. I had to install the **thunar-archive-plugin** in order to get any zip functionality. Apparently xubuntu-core doesn't come with it by default? Anyways. I'm logged in as root, and I test a small file on my desktop (such as text file), and it seems zip just fine with no problems. When I try to zip a large folder [3Gb] (it is a timeshift backup), it hangs for 5 minutes and then produces no zip file at all.

not sure what im doing wrong here. I'm running on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: fyi:  if you're seeking help on IRC, you need to be more patient... as you're asking volunteers, and not employees...  this site makes more sense if you can't leave an irc session open waiting for a reply..

Comment: @guiverc I closed my browser by accident. So I just decided to make a thread instead. Sorry about that.

Comment: no need to apologize.. I'd help here equally if I could.. just mentioned it as IRC is great if you're patient  (#ubuntu can be used by flavors, and you'll usually get answers faster unless it's very specific to a flavor; xubuntu-core likely needed to be in #xubuntu)